# Why does php-fpm (nginx) process not close and keep accumulating?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I have the following Nginx php-fpm5.6 settings

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 150
min_spare_servers) / 2
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 25

Each child process is around 91MB and I have 16GB of of ram.

When the max number of children is reached I start to get errors in the log along the lines of:

```
- connect() to unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream

- failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

Ultimately I end up having to restart php5.6-fpm to get everything working again.

I don't understand why there are so many open child processes that don't appear to be used. I've attached a screenshot of htop which looks like there are a lot of php-fpm not consuming any ram or cpu time. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/11kEjgcMDyc4EDbJU7DE_y87V6RRJ4ekN/view?usp=sharing)

Any ideas on how to solve / diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're using socket_connect() for this task? Whatever the case, you should be able to close the resource of the connection you've created by using code similar to:

```
$connection = socket_connect(...);
// ... code ...
socket_close($connection);
```

Perhaps you're using a for loop or something to create many connections, but are not closing them until after?

If you could post some of your code, that would be awesome :)

Hope this helps, thanks

Comment: hi Gatty, I ended up settings a request_terminate_timeout to 300. It was commented out. I can only assume that a php process was left open (and really idle) and once I ran out of workers it crashed. I'm still not sure of the root cause as there was no change to the codebase.

Comment: so turns out that we had a problem with our elastic search. The search results coming back from elastic search didn't complete and left the php process open. Adding the timeout helped but didn't fully resolve the problem